# JBoss Fuse Camel Route Editor: How to write multicast doing request-response fanout calls, and aggregating all responses into one message sent on?

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse

I'm using "Fuse Tooling Routes Editor" (aka "Fuse Integration Editor", aka "JBoss Fuse Tooling Apache Camel Editor"), described for example [here](http://tools.jboss.org/features/apachecamel.html). The version is "Nightly build version 8.0.0.v20150805-1820-H573-MASTER".

I'd like to create a Camel route having a [multicast](http://camel.apache.org/multicast.html) which aggregates the responses it receives from the components it sends a message to, and then forwards the aggregate to a single final receiver. This is certainly doable in Camel, as one of the parameters of a multicast, `strategyRef`, has the description:

> Refers to an AggregationStrategy to be used to assemble the replies from the multicasts, into a single outgoing message from the Multicast. By default Camel will use the last reply as the outgoing message.

However, when I write the following set of routes in my camel-context.xml (which compiles and runs fine):

```
<route>
  <from uri="direct:a"/>
  <setExchangePattern pattern="InOut"/>
  <multicast strategyRef="x">
    <to uri="direct:b"/>
    <to uri="direct:c"/>
  </multicast>
  <log message="This flow works!"/>
  <to uri="mock:p"/>
</route>

<route>
  <from uri="direct:b"/>
  <to uri="mock:q"/>
</route>

<route>
  <from uri="direct:c"/>
  <to uri="mock:r"/>
</route>
```

and then click to go to the visual editor, it produces the following (incorrect) picture:

[image]

When I switch back to the XML editing, my routes are automatically changed to:

```
<route>
  <from uri="direct:a"/>
  <setExchangePattern pattern="InOut"/>
  <log message="This flow works!"/>
  <to uri="mock:p"/>
</route>
<route>
  <from uri="direct:b"/>
  <to uri="mock:q"/>
</route>
<route>
  <from uri="direct:c"/>
  <to uri="mock:r"/>
</route>
```

And on switching to the editor once again, I get the picture:

[image]

This seems like a bug in the editor, but perhaps I'm doing something wrong here?

Many thanks!

**Edit:**

We found that indeed this used to be an [issue logged](http://issues.jboss.org/browse/FUSETOOLS-771) with the Fuse Camel editor, which however should have been fixed in version 7.1 of the tooling.

Answer (score 1):

that seems to be a bug in the editor. Thank you for reporting it.
I reopened the original issue in Jira. You can track the progress there.

Lars